# PHP print all the values inside while without repeat html

Tags: php, mysql, css

i got a problem with my php script.
I can't figure out how to print the values of my last query inside the same div with a while cycle, without repeat the div! Here's the code.

```
$query_serie = "SELECT nome_serie FROM serie";
$result_serie = mysql_query($query_serie);
while ($row_serie = mysql_fetch_array($result_serie)) {
    echo '<h4 class="intestazione_catalogo"><span>serie:</span> '.$row_serie['nome_serie'].'</h4>';

    $query_finitura = "SELECT nome_finitura FROM finitura JOIN serie ON finitura.id_serie = serie.id_serie WHERE nome_serie = '" .$row_serie['nome_serie']. "'";
    $result_finitura = mysql_query($query_finitura);
    while ($row_finitura = mysql_fetch_array($result_finitura)) {
        echo '<div class="finitura_catalogo">'.$row_finitura['nome_finitura'].'</div>'; 

        $query_codice = "SELECT codice FROM codice JOIN finitura ON codice.id_finitura = finitura.id_finitura LEFT JOIN serie ON finitura.id_serie = serie.id_serie WHERE visibile = 'si' AND nome_finitura = '".$row_finitura['nome_finitura']."'";
        $result_codice = mysql_query($query_codice);
        while ($row_codice = mysql_fetch_array($result_codice)) {
            echo '<div class="codice_catalogo">'.$row_codice['codice'].'</div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
    }
}
```

I need to ouput something like this
[image]

and following the others blocks and go on...
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting divisions outside the while loop. Something like this:

```
<div class="codice_catalogo">
while ($row_codice = mysql_fetch_array($result_codice)) {
echo $row_codice['codice'];
}
</div>
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried, but it seems to create a <div class="codice_catalogo"> inside another <div class="codice_catalogo"> because before the last while there is another while!

Comment: Is it possible to show me the output you are getting??

Comment: It' works! I was wrong because i closed the php tag, instead put the opening of the div inside the previous while like you said! Thanks for the help, now i can style everything with css and i'm done! =)